# delete with order by on a de-normalized table

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

I need to perform delete operation(with oldest data first) on a de-normalized table which does not have any unique ID. We are considering date as parameter 
while deciding the oldest data. But for each date their would be 600K records.And as table is very large the delete opertaion will be done in batches(Loop with rownum)
I used below query but this one is throwing error as 'data manipulation operation not legal on this view'. But I am sure that temp is object type of table.

`delete from (Select A.*,rownum as rn from (select * from temp order by date) A) B where B.rn<10`

Please let me know any alternative suggestions.

Thanks Kifinity your solution worked but now i am confused how to make it work to delete huge number of records.. I have around 10 millions of records and need to delete them in batches. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your statement, everything after `delete from` is an *inline view*. You can't delete from an inline view; your statement has to be `delete from TABLE`, e.g.

```
delete from temp
where rowid in (select rowid as rid
                from (select * from temp order by date)
                where rownum < 10)
```

Edit: as requested, here's an example as part of a PL/SQL loop.

```
begin
  loop
    delete from temp
    where rowid in (select rowid as rid
                    from (select * from temp order by date)
                    where rownum < 1000);
    if SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 then exit; end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: what if I have around 10 millions of records and I put a loop around this delete query and delete it in batches of around 1000 at a time. How will that be possible? Could you please suggest something.

Comment: Are you asking how to do that? If so I updated my answer.